# Why is there a jump on query planner cost when using a window function on Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-optimization

I encountered a weird behavior of the query planner in Amazon Redshift: at certain cases, like when a window function is used, the cost would jump by 10000. Usually, it's after the "Network" step.

My problem with that is that sometimes I do need to use window functions, and comparing costs between alternatives becomes impossible since The ratio between running times of the queries is not proportionate to the ratio of their costs (it is relatively proportionate if you look at the cost of the window function without the multiplication by 10000).

Here's a simplified example, compare these 2 queries:

```
-- Query #1: running time 2m 48s, cost 1000017902760.42
explain
select 
    first_value(timestamp) over (order by timestamp rows 
        between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
from table_with_timestamps as l
limit 1
;
-- Query #2: running time 10 sec, cost 1549471.30
explain
select 
    min(timestamp)
from table_with_timestamps
```

Could someone explain more about optimizing window functions and generally about this "network" step which is not clear to me?

Thanks.

Comment: do your real world query times correspond with the cost estimate at all? looks like no. - so i personally would focus on run times.

Comment: No, but the ratio of the costs of 2 queries I want to compare usually shows the ratio between their running times. The cost in itself is meaningless, but in relation to other queries costs it can be informational. Is that understood? Am I totally wrong in that?

Comment: you understand the massive amount of extra processing required in the first instance? can you change the example to reflect your real world use case?

Comment: the reason - redshift has to calculate the window metric for every row in your table. now, because of your window parameters they are always the same result but it wont know that. e.g. you might have a `rows between` that causes the results to vary.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the essential huge difference in processing, but the addition to the cost seems arbitrary in every case (and it's always times 10000), and that is what I was curious about. The thing is, in some cases (not in the example, but in my use-case) there is a real dillema between window and aggregate functions. I'll try and update my real use-case and see if it helps to clarify myself. @JonScott